# CDK command not found - macOS

Tags: aws-cdk

I have installed node, aws-cdk successfully. but when I run cdk --version/cdk doc , the terminal doesn't recognise CDK commands.

I am on mac OS, and I am new user of Mac, if some one can help, what path variable i need to set and how to set it.

Many thanks,

Comment: I suggest you try using homebrew:
https://brew.sh/
https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/aws-cdk

Otherwise maybe paste here the commands you used to install and the error message

Comment: I used npm install 'aws-cdk', to install cdk, in my personal laptop it works fine, but in my office laptop it doesnt work

Comment: maybe try `npm install 'aws-cdk' -g` ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm on macOs too and running this command from terminal helped me to fix the **CDK command not found**  issue:
`export PATH=$PATH:$(npm get prefix)/bin`

Then run  `cdk --version`.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue although I installed cdk using [homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/aws-cdk)

When I run `brew doctor`, it showed that `aws-cdk` was not linked.

Solution was to run `brew link aws-cdk`